# Javascript One-Liner Debugging

Tags: javascript, algorithm

After running the 'ol factorial recursive one-liner through jsperf for the millionth time, I decided to try something a little more interesting ... but it isn't working!

```
function n(cap){
    return (function y(x){
        return ((x < cap) ? x^2/y(x+1)+2*x-1 : 1)
    }(1))
}
```

which should work (and return an increasingly precise real value for greater values of 'cap'), however; when run against the numbers 0-19, it produces the following output in Chrome's console:

```
1 (x2)
2
0
2 (x16)
```

I'm at a loss. When stepped through, given the call stack, it's obviously recursing but fails to return anything other than natural numbers. Any thoughts?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, it looks familiar, but I can't place it... What is `1.2732395...`?

Comment: @cwolves: I think this is an approximation of the square root of the golden ratio

Comment: @josh.trow - thanks, looks like it: `1.618 ** .5 = 1.27200629`.  I'm not sure I've ever seen it before though.  Any uses?  (I know what the golden ratio is/is for)

Comment: @josh.trow -- correction, it's `4/π`, or 1/4 of a circle.  I imagine it's used to convert radians-->degrees (or visa-versa)

Comment: @cwolves: AAAAH that makes a lot more sense. How did you find that?

Comment: Was trying to figure out what it was -- I typed "1.2732395 * Pi" into google and got "4" (rather 3.9999999)  :P

Comment: Whoops; I'm still new to this and only now saw the '9 responses' alert -- apologies for the exceedingly slow reply. But yeah, it's 4/pi and was solely a challenge/coding trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's your `^`, which is a bitwise `xor`, ***not*** a power operator.  To raise something: `Math.pow(2, 10) == 1024`

All bitwise ops in JavaScript have an implicit cast-to-int, meaning `0^3.14159265358979323846 == 3`

Comment: Boy isn't that embarassing :|. And here I was thinking Javascript an incredible language for having an exponentiation operator!